# Answering Technical interview problems: To what lengths?

Tags: interviewing

One of the problems that I have always been pondering about is how to go about solving technical interview problems. For example, suppose I was asked, at an interview:

```
 Given an array of integers, remove all duplicates elements from it
```

For me, because a lot of my experience is in Java, I would just use libraries.

But it seems that the solution to those problems on the books are generally low level, or have some tricks.

TLDR: Is it acceptable to use libraries, high level abstractions with higher level languages to solve technical problems? Or are we supposed work with none of those tools?

Comment: this is more a developers question than a workplace issue.

Comment: [This answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/16799) on Programmers SE should help you.

Answer (score 3):

I'd likely ask in the interview as sometimes the key with those questions is to see what will be asked and what will be assumed. How do you ask if you have a question? How do you handle ambiguity that may pop up? This is often the key behind some of these things. In reality, there could be various answers to the question which is why seeking clarity is important.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it acceptable to use libraries, high level abstractions with higher level languages to solve technical problems?

**Maybe.** It depends on what point in the interview you're in, and what position you're applying for. If I asked an entry level programmer, then answering the library way may be expected. If I was asking a senior level programmer, I might want you to do it by hand.

In general, there is no harm with responding with the library way. If they want you to do it without libraries, they'll clarify.

Comment: Right, so then it is ok to assume, given any technical interview, that I can use whatever languages I want, whatever libraries I want

Comment: Especially since I am an intern, didn't even graduate with university yet

Comment: If the position is for a specific language, it might be better to use that language, if you can.

Comment: @Mantracker - if you are uncomfortable assuming, ask. If unspecified, feel free to use whatever. They'll correct you if needs be.

Comment: @Telastyn has it right: ASK whether there are additional constraints they haven't specified. Refining fuzzy requirements is going to be part of your job; they'll want to see you demonstrate that you can do so.

Comment: If you are applying for a more junior position, it would also improve your chances by responding with a by-hand approach. Therefore it's probably the best to *always* answer with a by-hand approach ;)